# How to use ListViewBuilder with switch button for dynamic JSON data in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Problem: Using the static Json I can easily set a certain number of switch buttons parallel to the ListView, but when the JSON data is dynamic in nature, I cannot understand how to use the switch button parallel to the ListView Builder?

Example

```
 Input
 MapIDs={upi282:1,upi219:1,upi211:0,upi236:0};// number of upi..'s increase or decrease based on fetching data from API
```

I want to use above Json for ListViewBuilder with switch button so that user can change key-value
And when click on the update button, it gets the updated JSON for the API.

Does anyone know how to implement it?

[image]

```
  Code:
MapIDs={upi282:1,upi219:1,upi211:0,upi236:0};// number of upi..'s increase or decrease
bool switch_Value=true;
Widget generateListandGetValue( MapIDs,int LengthofMap,switch_Value) {

return ListView.builder(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemCount:LengthofMap,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(
                '\nName- ${MapIDs[index]}\n',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
              ),

              trailing:
              Switch(
                value: switch_Value,
                onChanged: AlertsStatus,
                activeColor: greenColor,
                activeTrackColor: greenColor,
              ),
              //  onExpansionChanged: toggleAlertsStatus,
             selected: true,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    });
```

}

```
      void AlertsStatus(alertsOn) {
      setState(() {
      print(alertsOn);
      alertsOn ? _buttonStatus = 1 : _buttonStatus = 0;
      });
    }
```

I tried but could not understand how to use the switch button for dynamic JSON and return value

```
 output: {upi282:0,upi219:0,upi211:1,upi236:0}
```